# Everything but arrays in c++ are passed by value by default?

Tags: c++, stl, pass-by-reference

Everything in c++ , including the STL containers are passed by value . But the exception is Array which are passed by pointers . Right?

Why are arrays in c++ [eg: int a[5] ] are passed by pointers but the vectors are passed by value ? [By default]

edit: okay , `std::array` can be passed by value also , I wasn't aware of this .

code :

```
void fun_array(int a[])
{
    a[0]=10;
}



  void fun_vector(vector<int> v)
    {
        v[0]=10;
    }

    int main()
    {
        int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
        vector<int> v={1,2,3,4,5};
        fun_array(a);
        fun_vector(v);

        cout<<a[0]<<" "<<v[0];

    }
```

output : 10 1

Comment: Arrays  can _decay_ to pointers

Comment: What do you mean by arrays in C++? do you mean `std::array`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default *all* function arguments in C++ are passed by value.

Your confusion comes from the fact that the name of an array is actually a pointer to the first element of the array (eg. for the array `int a[6]`, `a` is a pointer to `a[0]`.

Unless the function parameter is explicitly a reference to a pointer, even pointer arguments are passed by value.

Comment: The name of an array is certainly _not_ a pointer to its first element, as you can see if you try `&a` or `sizeof(a)`, but it will _decay_ into one in most contexts.

Comment: Reference arguments are passed by reference. (duh...) Non-reference arguments are passed by value.

Comment: @rodrigo while technically true if you're writing a compiler, few beginners who are trying to understand why C++ arrays do what they do are going to do a deep reading of section 7.2 of ISO/IEC 14882:2017. Saying the name of the array acts like a pointer makes more sense when you see that *(1 + a) gives the same result as a[1], or that passing the name of the array as a parameter means the argument is a pointer passed by value.  It works, it lets them write working code they can reason about, and they don't have to worry about how to implement the symbol table in a compiler to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is passed by value if you don't specify otherwise. The case about C arrays is not an exception, but just that they degenerate into pointers. If you need a fixed size array in C++ code prefer using `std::array` instead of C arrays.

Then decide if you want to pass by value or by reference.

Related note: Even when passing containers, you might still want to pass by value, instead of by reference, **if** you are going to copy the container.